# Is it possible to pass a "PHP" variable that is passed by an URL as comparison element for a SQL query?

Tags: php, sql

I've set a local server using PHPMyAdmin, and I'm presenting some dynamic data that is stored in that server using some PHP, HTML and SQL. The problem is that whenever I pass a variable that is stored using `$variable = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["variable"]);` and then I use that variable in a SQL query similar to this one `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM assets WHERE variable="$variable";`. The array that is generated is empty.

When I do a `print_r($variable);`, I get the variable that the code is expecting, so I'm not sure why the query sends an empty array. Then, when I hardcode the SQL query with the value of print_r($variable), the correct array is obtained from the query.

Code in PHP that is not working

```
$variable = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["variable"]);

  print_r($_GET["location"]);

  // make SQL
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM assets WHERE variable="$variable"';
```

Where `$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'table');`
The connection is correct though

then for example when I hardcode it using the result I get from

`print_r($_GET["variable"]); prints N1 on the screen`

This PHP is working, but it won't be dynamic

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM assets WHERE variable="N1';
```

I'm expecting to see all the results were the field variable = to a `$_GET["variable"]`, where `$_GET["variable"]` is stored in `$variable`, but all I'm getting is an empty string.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: In order to use mysqli_real_escape_string you have to have establish the connection to your database first

Comment: yeap, I'm doing that in a different file that is included at the top
`$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'table');

  // check the connection
  if(!$conn){
    echo 'Connection error: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
  }`

Comment: Copy past this and will work "SELECT * FROM assets WHERE variable='$variable'";

Answer (score 0):

You could use a prepared  statement and binding param (for this you don't need  the real string escape id done by the msqli prepared and binding)

```
$conn= new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'your_db');
$myVar =  $_GET["location"]; 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM assets WHERE variable=?';

$query = $conn->prepare( $sql);
$query->bind_param('s',$myVar);
$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge, thanks for the help. I'm connecting to the localhost, and then I have this: 

      ` $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["location"]);

      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM assets WHERE location="$myVar"';

      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      // fetch the resulting rows as an array
      $myVarArray = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      // free result from memory
      mysqli_free_result($result);

      // close the connection to the database
      mysqli_close($conn); `

Comment: will this substitute the fetching, freeing the memory and closing the conn? sorry i'm a bit new to php and SQL

Comment: you comment have not sense  ..  to me  ..  anyway don't use php var in sql  ( even though they have been cleaned) use  ..  prepared  statement and binding param for a clean and sqlinjection free code ..

Comment: the you can free memory and close the connection but is not thist the point  --  .. anyway  ..  try and check for the correct result in $result  ..  content

Comment: Thank you @scaisEdge, after reading more about SQL and PHP functions, I had one command that was "clearing" the array. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may be solve issues.

```
   $conn= new mysqli("localhost","my_user", "my_password", "world");
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM assets WHERE variable='.$_POST["variable"];
   mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but my problem was that for some reason my array while passing a variable (or maybe at every time) was being cleared. Thanks for the help though :)